# Create a Unix shell script with 4 parameters

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file (for example `system.log`). I need to scan this file to find a specific string that must appear several times during a period of 5 minutes.

I imagine that I can make a script with 4 parameters:

- the location of the file
- the string to search
- the number of times that the string appears
- the period of time

If this script finds the string in the specified period of time it writes, for example, the message 'success'

Here's the begin of the script

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -x

#############
# VARIABLES #
#############

location="/moteurs/websphere/7.0/esb/managed01/logs/"
file="SystemOut.log"
pattern="WSV0605W: Thread \"SIBFAPInboundThreadPool"
string=$(grep -ic "${pattern}" ${location}/${file})
```

Now that I've defined my variables, I don't know how can I make a function that scans `SystemOut.log` every 5 minutes.

Comment: Please include sample input, desired output, the code you've tried so far, and describe what works or doesn't work.

Comment: Right.  SO is no "code for me" forum.  It is meant for specific questions.

Comment: You mean a *script* or *shell script*, not a *shell*. `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are shells; a program that runs under one of those shells is a *script*.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you kown how can I create this shell?

Yes. Use your favorite editor, write the shell script, execute it. You are done.

Comment: @devnull I couldn't see any other question in this question. HIH.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  This was the only question which you answered pretty well (and that explains the upvote :).

Comment: Don't forget that a correct answer does not justify a +1.  That is to be given if the answer is particular useful for you.  Is this one here really useful?

Answer (score 0):

Just a half answer, but maybe it gets you somewhere:

To run something repeatedly every five minutes, you can make a loop with a sleep:

```
while true
do
  echo "I'm doing something!"  # replace this by the actual code
  sleep $[5*60]
done
```

This will run the code (here just an `echo`) every five minutes. — Okay, plus the time the code needs, so do not rely on the time being accurate; to get it accurate, you can use

```
while sleep $[ 5*60 - $(date +%s) % (5*60) ]
do
  echo "I'm doing something!"  # replace this by the actual code
done
```

This will always wait for a full 5-minute point on the clock before executing the code.